# User verification changing 'registered user hashed password', preventing login

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm, email-verification

User registers with a bcrypt hashed password. After proceding with email verification through mailtrap/nodemailer and successfully verifing user status to true, the login fails, returning 'unmatched password", because it is changing stored user hashed password. If I skip the verification step and proceed with login directly, it will work fine.  So how do I do 'user verification' without changing stored hashed password in my code below?

```js
 async login(req: Request, res: Response){
              // Get user from database
        const userRepository = getRepository(User);
        const { email, password } = req.body;

        if (!(email && password)) {
          console.error('Empty name or password!');
          return res.status(400).send({
            error: 'Empty name or password'
          });
        }
    
        const user = await userRepository.findOne({ where: { email } });

        let storedUserPass = user!.password;
        console.log(password)        //-> consoles plain typed text
        console.log(storedUserPass)  //-> consoles encrypted password

        const isValidPassword = await bcrypt.compareSync(password, storedUserPass as string);
        console.log(isValidPassword) //-> consoles false

        if(!user) {
          return res.send(`User doesn t exist! `);
        }    

        else if (!user.isVerified) {
          
          return res.send('Your Email has not been verified. Please do so!');

        }
        
        else if(!isValidPassword) {
          return res.send('Password doesn t match')
        }
         else {
              
        // Sing JWT, valid for 1 hour
        const token = jwt.sign(
          { id: user.id, email: user.email }, 
          process.env.NODE_ENV,          
          { expiresIn: "1d" }
        );
        
   
        res.json({
          user,
          token
        });
        }

    },
```

```js
async create(req: Request, res: Response) {        

        const verificationToken = await crypto.randomBytes(8).toString('hex');
        const { name, email, password, role, isVerified } = req.body;
        const date = new Date();
          
        try {
          const userRepository = getRepository(User); 
          const tokenRepository = getRepository(Token); 
  
          //User validation
            const data = {
              name,
              email,
              password,
                      
            }    

           
            const schema = Yup.object().shape({
                name: Yup.string().required('Name required.').max(60),
                email: Yup.string().email("Invalid Email.").required(),
                password: Yup.string().required().min(4).max(10), 
            })
  
            await schema.validate(data, {
                abortEarly: false
            });       
  
          const userExists = await userRepository.findOne({ where: { email }})

        if(userExists) {  
          return res.send(`Usuário com email cadastrado ${email} já existe!` );

        } else {
          const token = tokenRepository.create({token: verificationToken, tokenDate: date})
          await tokenRepository.save(token);

          const user = userRepository.create({ name, email, password, role: role || "basic", isVerified, date, token})
          
          console.log(user.password) // consoles plain text
          
          await userRepository.save(user); 
          
          console.log(user.password) //consoles encrypted text    
          
          
              return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                const transp = transport;
                var mailOptions = {
                  from: 'Administrador <c3e26a9df0-703049@inbox.mailtrap.io>',
                  to: email,
                  subject: 'Account verification link!',
                  html: `<h2>Olá ${user.name}</h2><br/>
                  <p>Finalize o seu cadastro clicando neste <a href="http://${req.headers.host}/users/confirmation/${user.email}/${verificationToken}" target="_about"  style="color: blue, text-derocation: none"}>Link</a>`
                  
                }
            
               
               transp.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error: Err){
                   if (error) {
                      return res.status(500).send({msg:'Technical Issue!,Please click on resend for verify your Email.'});
                     
                   } 
                  else {
                    return res.send('A verification email has been sent to ' + user.email + '. It will be expire after one day. If you not get verification Email click on resend token.');
      
                  });
                })  
               
               }

      } catch(err) {
        return res.status(404).send({ err: "Failed to send email."})
      }

    
    },
```

//TYPEORM USER MODEL:

```
@Entity('users') 
export default class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column({
      unique: true
    })
    email: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;
  
    @Column()
    role: string;
    default: 'basic'
    enum: ["basic", "supervisor", "admin"];

    @Column({
      type: "datetime"
    })
    date!: Date;

    @Column({
      default: false
    })
    isVerified: boolean;       

    @BeforeInsert() 
    @BeforeUpdate() 
    hashPassword() {  
      this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, 8); // salt de 8
    }
  
    checkIfUnencryptedPasswordIsValid(unencryptedPassword: string) {
      return bcrypt.compareSync(unencryptedPassword, this.password);
    }


    @OneToMany(() => Orphanage, orphanage => orphanage.user, {
        cascade: ['insert' , 'update']
    })     
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id'}) 
    orphanages: Orphanage[];


    @OneToOne(type => Token)
    @JoinColumn()
    token: Token;

}
```

```js
    async confirmEmail(req: Request, res: Response) {
      try {
        const userRepository = getRepository(User);  
        const tokenRepository = getRepository(Token);  
  
        const tokenExists = await tokenRepository.findOne({ token: req.params.token });    
        tokenExists!.tokenDate 
  
        if( !tokenExists ) {
          return res.status(400).send({msg:'Your verification link may have expired. Please click on resend for verify your Email.'});
        } else {
          
         const user = await userRepository.findOne({where: { token: tokenExists,  email: req.params.email }})

         //user not exist
          if(!user) {
            return res.status(401).send({msg:'We were unable to find a user for this verification. Please SignUp!'});

          } // user is already verified
          else if (user.isVerified){
              return res.status(200).send('User has been already verified. Please Login');

          } else { //verify user
            user.isVerified = true;
            await userRepository.save(user);
            console.log(user)     // -> hashed user.password is different from when created user after user is verified.  
            return res.status(200).send('Your account has been successfully verified')
          }
        }
      } catch(err) {
        return res.status(500).send({err: "Sorry, it could not be validated!"});
      }
        
    },
```

Comment: Accept my answer and upvote if it solves your problem otherwise leave a comment I will try to improve it.

Comment: you have set the default value of isVarified = false
when isVarified is false else if (!user.isVerified) will return true. and it will generate error.
remove this code block:      
  else if (!user.isVerified) {
          
          return res.send('Your Email has not been verified. Please do so!');

        }

Comment: Shakir, I did it and it doesn t work. After registering new user, 'isVerified'  gets set to false, and in login,  'isValidPassword' returns correctly to true. My problem is,  after e-mail verification, 'isVerified' is then correctly set to true, but  'isValidPassword' starts returning set to false, so it won t login. Even if I comment  block else if (!user.isVerified)...

Comment: Okay, check your plain text and encrypted password on the following link: 
https://bcrypt-generator.com/
if it does not match then your encryption method is not right.

Comment: I think I found the issue: Once creating user, hashed password matches plai text, and after verifying user, it doesn t. Please see 'confirmEmail' code I just added above. I compared hashed user.password in console from 'create' and 'confirmEmail', noticed they are different. That s why I can t log in after email verification, cuzz it will change the hashed password. So what is changing the hashed password in confirmEmail ? Would there be any hack to keep hashed password from 'create' after 'confirEmail' procedure ?

Comment: I could not understand your full code flow if my answer helped you upvote it and accept the answer by clicking the tick mark.

Answer (score 0):

Using `?` in `user?.password` is not a valid way. The symbol`?` is used in the ternary operator. The ternary operator needs three parameters and you are not providing these parameters.

**solution:** format your code as given below. I used the `!` operator in `user!.password`. This operator in `user!` ensures your transpiler that the user will not be undefined. So, before using this operator you should check whether a user is defined or not, in this way:

```
if(!user) {
    return res.send(`User doesn t exist! `);
   }
```

If you don't check the user before using `!` you may get a run-time error in the case of an undefined user. No need to use `as string`.

**Changed Block in your code:**

```
const user = await userRepository.findOne({ where: { email } });
//check user immediately after getting it to avoid errors
if(!user) {
    return res.send(`User doesn t exist! `);
   }    
let storedUserPass = user!.password;
const isValidPassword = await bcrypt.compareSync(password, storedUserPass);
```

**Now your code will look like:**

```
 async login(req: Request, res: Response){
              // Get user from database
        const userRepository = getRepository(User);
        const { email, password } = req.body;

        if (!(email && password)) {
          console.error('Empty name or password!');
          return res.status(400).send({
            error: 'Empty name or password'
          });
        }
    
        const user = await userRepository.findOne({ where: { email } });
        if(!user) {
          return res.send(`User doesn t exist! `);
        }    

        let storedUserPass = user!.password;
        const isValidPassword = await bcrypt.compareSync(password, storedUserPass);

        if (!user.isVerified) {
          
          return res.send('Your Email has not been verified. Please do so!');

        }
        
        else if(!isValidPassword) {
          return res.send('Password doesn t match')
        }
         else {
              
        // Sing JWT, valid for 1 hour
        const token = jwt.sign(
          { id: user.id, email: user.email }, 
          process.env.NODE_ENV,          
          { expiresIn: "1d" }
        );
        
   
        res.json({
          user,
          token
        });
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you Shakir, very much. But I keep getting the same problem with 'unmatched password'.

Comment: Have you encrypted the password before saving it in DB?

Comment: const encryptedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(userInput.password, 10)
use same library "bcrypt" to encrypt and compare.

Answer (score 0):

Shakir Aqeel, please do not consider my last answer, I got confused, the prob has nothing to do with token.

But I have always used same library to encrypt the password when creating user, located on User model:

```js
   hashPassword() {  
      this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, 8); 
    }
```

In the User controller:

```js
console.log(user.password) -> plain typed password          
await userRepository.save(user);
console.log(user.password) -> encrypted password
```

If I register a new user with verification status as 'true', it will login with no problem....

Comment: show your user schema and code block where you are registering users and exact console errors. edit in question part and inform me with comment. Don't show question details in answer otherwise, people will report you.

Comment: Ok, I did! Just registered new user, and same issue again. Stuck on 'isValidPassword ' validation on Login. Take a look at what several consoles are returning on Login code I just edited.